# Is there any design reason why the optional chaining operator doesn't work well with a union of classes in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have an union of classes:

`type X = ClassA | ClassB | ClassC;`

ClassA and ClassC share a common method called `methodY`.

Why can't I use a simple optional chaining operator to call for methodY?

```
class ClassA {
    methodY() {
        return 'a';
    }
}
class ClassB {}
class ClassC {
    methodY() {
        return 'c';
    }
}
type X = ClassA | ClassB | ClassC;

function getMethodY(x: X) {
    return x.methodY?.(); // Error: Property 'methodY' does not exist on type 'ClassB'.
}
```

Instead I have to keep using these patterns: `methodY in doc && doc.methodY()` or `if (methodY in doc) doc.methodY()` which are very similar to the optional chaining operator?

What are the design reasons why checking for `methodY in doc` should be any different than checking directly in the operator?

Comment: I assume TypeScript has to (or wants to) distinguish between "`doc.foo` doesn't exist for any constituent of `X`)" and "`doc.foo` exists for some, but not all, constituents of `X`". I expect an explicit runtime check like `methodY in doc` allows for type narrowing to change the static type of `doc` from `X` to something like `ClassA | ClassC`.

Comment: You haven't shown what doc is. Can you share a working example?

Comment: @schwyzl Sure, I just edited the example to a fully contained version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of conversations on this topic, like: (and also other issues linked to them)

- [Properties in any members of Union should be Optional (or | undefined) · Issue #42775 · microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42775)
- [Property in subset of branches of a union type should be accessible for checking against undefined and result in narrowing type of object · Issue #49933 · microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49933).

Let me quote an example here:

```js
type Message =
  { kind: "close" } |
  { kind: "data", payload: object }

function handle(m: Message) {
  switch (m.kind) {
    case "close":
      console.log("closing!");
      // forgot 'break;' here
    case "data":
      updateBankAccount(m.payload);
  }
}
```

In this example, "type does not exist" can help you catch accidentally used properties. If undefined values are accepted at where it is used, treating it as `undefined` cannot detect the error.

Another example is that you may accidentally use `if (a.length)` when you actually want to check `if ('length' in a)`.

In summary, although both the current `in` operator narrowing and the unimplemented `undefined` check narrowing are unsound in some examples, the `in` operator is more explicit and may cause fewer errors in other situations.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56440
In this they mention optional chaining is indeed equivalent to the 'in operator' but they don't narrow it because it's "easier to make mistakes". Like the "optional chaining" is too easy to misuse and less explicit, like you said. Its unrelated with accepting undefined values tough.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to design reasons but if you want to kill the error and not guard around the method in the function you could extend an abstact class that declares the method.

```
abstract class ClassP{
    methodY?():void
}

class ClassA extends ClassP{
    methodY() {
        return 'a';
    }
}
class ClassB extends ClassP {}
class ClassC extends ClassP {
    methodY() {
        return 'c';
    }
}
type X = ClassA | ClassB | ClassC;

function getMethodY(x: X) {
    return x.methodY?.();
}
```

See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQQwRgzgLgTiDGVjwDYghYBhNGAKA3gLABQw5wAtgKZQAWA9gCYCaA-ABQCUAXAG4MAlkwDcpAL6lSqdJhyyAgsGoAPKNQB2TObgiFSFKrUatuwYmUMUYtAK4wNwAOQgnYy%20UkkvMjNl0AQspqmtr%20snjmPrrhGFjB6lo6EeYGFDT0zCxmFlbWdg7O8G5pnhKkUACeAA7UwAAawAC8sRBKAD6tQZ3yce6kAGa2GoiCDI4A5rQAssZZHCo8DVypHsA2UPaOKgB0GSbsO9zu4kA)

Agree it would be nice if the optional chaining operator handled it though.

Comment: I actually liked this solution a lot. I didn't knew you could declare optional methods like this.

Comment: I would suggest `abstract methodY(): void` and `ClassB` does not extend `ClassP`. Then you can use `instanceof ClassP` for type guard.

Comment: This just complicates the code and doesn't address the issue. You don't need an inheritance hierarchy to express this